# Multiple Ubuntu Server SSH Connections

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm trialing a ubuntu server 12.04 LTS to replace a Windows Server that I use but I have got a little stuck with SSH

I'm currently able to SSH into the server but I need to have multiple persistent SSH connections as I have at least 3 applications that need to run in the server and still be able to access their terminals to issue commands to the applications. At the moment this is fine if I use the physical terminals of the machine as I can just jump between the three terminals I use but remotely doing this is the issue.

As I'm not entirely familiar with this side of linux I'm not sure if this is even possible to do or how to even get around this issue.

EDIT : I should also add that if the SSH connection is disconnected I should be able to re open that connection and with the other two which I think will be the biggest problem with doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) terminal multiplexers will allow you do disconnect/reconnect from/to remote ssh terminal sessions. [Byobu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byobu_%28software%29) is an excellent enhancement on top of the previous two. The remote sessions can have multiple terminals open simultaneously and can also be named, so you can have has many as you like.

Comment: Awesome that was so much easier than I had expected. Thanks for that.